# Нарисовать график на React с помощью библиотеки

Tags: reactjs, frontend, mui

Всем привет! Кто знает, подскажите, пожалуйста, как нарисовать вот такой график с помощью библиотеки Mui X, ну или с помощью другой библиотеки.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вся сложность заключается в следующем. В зависимости от определенных значений, которые передаются в качестве данных для графика, отрезки и задний фон на графике должны быть разных цветов.
Данные примерно такие:

```js
const data = [
    {
      "height": 145,
      "distance": 0,
      "surface": "SAND",
      "maxSpeed": "SLOW"
    },
    {
      "height": 157,
      "distance": 1342,
      "surface": "SAND",
      "maxSpeed": "SLOW"
    },
    {
      "height": 134,
      "distance": 1732,
      "surface": "SAND",
      "maxSpeed": "SLOW"
    },
    {
      "height": 206,
      "distance": 1276,
      "surface": "ASPHALT",
      "maxSpeed": "FAST"
    },
    {
      "height": 124,
      "distance": 1574,
      "surface": "GROUND",
      "maxSpeed": "NORMAL"
    }
]
```

Где цвет отрезка зависит от значения MaxSpeed, а цвет заднего фона от Surface.

Comment: Не знаю как Mui X, есть прям в [демо на echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-sections) график, как вам нужен